# bind gridview onkeypress on textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

So I already have a gridview being updated based on the number typed in textbox with OnTextChanged event. The problem is the gridview only updates when the textbox loses control and I want it to bind data when a key is pressed based on the number entered. I already have tried an ajax call to a web method or call a code behind function from javascript and none has worked

this is my input textbox

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upNumComps" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNumComps" runat="server" Text="Nº de Componentes " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red; margin-right: 5px;"> * </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumComps" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtNumComps_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNumComps" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="txtNumComps" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

the gridview is here

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDetComps" CssClass="mGrid1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="grvComponentes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ForeColor="#001f3f" GridLines="None" Style="text-align: center;">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nº" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRowNumber" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' runat="server" Style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Componente">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComponente" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 5px;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvComponente" ForeColor="red" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtComponente" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Base">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBase" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 5px;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBase" ForeColor="red" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBase" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comprimento">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComprimento" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtComprimento_TextChanged" Style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 5px;"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvComprimento" ForeColor="red" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtComprimento" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtComprimento" EventName="TextChanged" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind function

```
protected void txtNumComps_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rowCount = "";
    if (!CheckInt(txtNumComps.Text) || txtNumComps.Text == "0")
    {
        txtNumComps.Text = "";
        txtNumComps.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Insira um número");
        rowCount = "0";
        ViewState["rowCount"] = rowCount;
        grvComponentesBind();
    }
    else if (CheckInt(txtNumComps.Text) && txtNumComps.Text != "0")
    {
        rowCount = txtNumComps.Text;
        ViewState["rowCount"] = rowCount;
        grvComponentesBind();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's an update to what I have managed so far.

I have added this javascript function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function RefreshUpdatePanel(id) {
        debugger
        __doPostBack(id, '');
        document.getElementById(id).blur(id);
        document.getElementById(id).focus(id);
    };
</script>
```

and on the textbox I have changed to this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumComps" runat="server" onkeyup="RefreshUpdatePanel(this.id);" OnTextChanged="txtNumComps_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

However it does what I wanted to, it shows a number of rows  based on number typed on key up now instead of updating by clicking out of the textbox but there is still a problem, the textbox loses focus after just pressing a key and even if i tried to set focus programatically it didn't work or it set the cursor behind the previous number typed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to handle it this way, but I suppose you could do:

`txtNumComps.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "document.Form1.submit();");`

Would be irritating to most users imo...

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a custom `keyup` event to that textbox. In that event set the focus to another element and the `TextChanged` event will fire.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumComps" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtNumComps_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= txtNumComps.ClientID %>').keyup(function () {
            $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

However with this approach, if a user want to enter `12`, there will be an useless PostBack.

Comment: similar to what i just changed, this is the problem i'm trying to solve now, how to regain focus and show the cursor after the typed number